# Celery/SQS task retry gone haywire - how to get rid of it?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

We've got Celery/SQS set up for asynchronous task management. We're running Django for our framework. We have a celery task that has a self.retry() in it. Max_retries is set to 15. The retry is happening with an exponential backoff and takes 182 hours to complete all 15 retries.

Last week, this task went haywire, I think due to a bug in our code not properly handling a service outage. It resulted in exponential creation (retrying?) of the same celery task.  It eventually used up all available memory and the worker crashed. Restarting the worker results in another crash a couple hours later, since all those tasks (and their retries) keep retrying and spawning new retries until we run out of memory again. Ultimately we ended up with nearly 600k tasks created!

We need our workers to ignore all the tasks with a specific celery GUID. Ideally we could just get rid of them for good. I was going to use revoke() but, per documentation (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/workers.html#commands), this is only implemented for Redis and RabbitMQ, not SQS. Furthermore, when I go to the SQS service in the AWS console, it's showing zero messages in flight so it's not like I can just flush it.

Is there a way to delete or revoke a specific message from SQS using the Celery task ID? Or is there another way to fix this problem? Obviously we need to fix our code so we don't get into this situation again, but first we need to get our worker up and running because without it our website has reduced functionality. Thanks!